# How to use regEx expression to replace "/" for "-" in string

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im trying to replace "/" for "-" in my date string but when i try to make a regex expression i cant use the "/" because it turn the expression into a comment or acts like the expression is blank

[This is when it comments out the expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6784.png)
[This is when it assumes that the expression is blanck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOc79.png)

Thank your for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\` in front of reserved characters to turn them into literals. So if you want `/` to be literally interpreted, write `\/`.

**Edit** (more info)

The act of doing so is called "escaping". Check out this regexr I've set up for you https://regexr.com/4qtbp

Answer (score 1):

As `/` is a special character used in the Regex syntax, you need to escape it by adding a backslash just before to turns it into literal :

```
this.datasend.replace('/\/g', '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use escape character `\`

```js
var x = "a/b/v/c".replace(/\//g, "-");
console.log(x);
```